# Apify Scrapy template returns Attribute error

Tags: python, web-scraping, apify

I install the Scrapy template from Apify CLI and run it as [intructed](https://blog.apify.com/web-scraping-with-scrapy/#creating-a-new-actor). I don't do any changes.

When I deploy it to Apify, the same problem occurs. Even when I used the same template from Apify console and create a new one, the same error happens again.

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'AsyncioSelectorReactor' object has no attribute '_handleSignals'
```

I'm using Python 3.11 on M1 Macbook.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug on Scrapy's (or even Twisted's) side - https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/6024.

Adding the following constraint:

```
Twisted < 23.0.0
```

to your `requirements.txt` file should solve the issue.

We already updated the Scrapy template this way (https://github.com/apify/actor-templates/pull/179).

It should work now.